# Pasar datos de un datagridview a otro en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

```cs
coleccionY = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDatos.Rows.Count - 1);
coleccionX = dgvDatos.Columns.Count;

for (int j = 0; j < coleccionX; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < coleccionY; i++)
    {
        coleccionDato = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDatos.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
        dgvBidimensional.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = coleccionDato.ToString();
    }
    dgvBidimensional.Rows.Add();
}
```

Este código se utiliza en el evento click de un botón. No ejecuta nada más que este código en el proceso que necesito.

Pasa los datos del dgv de arriba hacia el dgv de abajo. Cada columna(c1, c2...c10) deben pasar como filas. Es decir en el datagrid de abajo debería estar: el 0 en X y el 8 en Y, el 0 en X y el 10 en Y así sucesivamente, hasta llegar al 1 y al 4 (Es lo mismo decir que pasa toda la fila 0 del dgv de arriba, a la columna 0 del dgv de abajo y así, solo que ya lo probé de las 2 formas y me ocurre el mismo error). Lo reviso paso a paso, y recoge bien todos los datos, pero cuando finaliza todo, me muestra el dgv de abajo así como en la imagen. Borra todos los datos excepto los últimos 2, que se muestran ahí. Solo el 1 y el 4 quedan pasados (mirar dgv de abajo)

Adjunto una foto para que se entienda mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Aclaración:** No busco que me pasen el código, pero sí que me digan si hay algo mal.

He pasado datos de forma ordenada, es decir de mayor a menor desde un dgv a otro y lo he podido hacer bien. Pero acá hay algo que no está funcionando como debería.

Ya busqué por otros foros y preguntas, pero ninguno responde al error que tengo acá. Son similares, pero no iguales los errores que tienen en comparación, pero los he revisado y pareciera estar todo OK.

¿Alguna idea por qué pasa eso o qué estoy haciendo mal?

Obviamente, cabe resaltar que he buscado esto, pero todo lo que encontré me llevó a este código que me sigue haciendo lo mismo y no logro hacer que funcione como necesito.

Comment: Hola, puedes decirme si te resultó útil la respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No uses el método:

```
dgv.Rows.Add();
```

Dentro del **ciclo for**, usa una sobrecarga del mismo antes de entrar en los ciclos:

```
dgv.Rows.Add(x);
```

Donde x es un número que representa la cantidad de filas a insertar que en tu caso sería la cantidad de columnas del primer **DataGridView**, por tanto se insertarían x filas vacías.

Lo qué pasa con el **método Add()**, sin ningún parámetro es que el añade la fila en donde se encuentra el foco del **DataGridView** en ese momento, que puede ser cualquier fila.

Comment: Ahora entendí, listo. Muchísimas gracias hermano/a. Era simplemente eso y no me daba cuenta.

Comment: Si, ya lo hice. Me demoré porque estaba probándolo ahora. Gracias!

Comment: @JoelPallero, disculpa, pero le diste un voto, no la márcaste como aceptada, te agradecería que también la marcara como aceptada, gracias y disculpa las molestias

Comment: Tenés razón, ahora si. Mala mía. Saludos!